# nvd3 multiBarChart achive data for comparison multiple values

Tags: angular, nvd3.js

How can I Achive  data for  nvd3 multiBarChart

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Did you look at [the multibarchart example](http://nvd3-community.github.io/nvd3/examples/multiBarChart.html)? You just need to make sure that your datapoints have the same xValue.

The code they used to generate the data is:

```
var negative_test_data = new d3.range(0,3).map(function(d,i) {
    return {
        key: 'Stream' + i,
        values: new d3.range(0,11).map( function(f,j) {
            return {
                y: 10 + Math.random()*100 * (Math.floor(Math.random()*100)%2 ? 1 : -1),
                x: j
            }
        })
    };
});
```

Note that x: j will result in each series sharing the same x values.